# Iframe source needs protocol with URL?

Tags: iframe

I gave input to iframe `src` as `http://www.espncricinfo.com/` it works.

I gave input to iframe `src` as `www.espncricinfo.com` it doesn't work.  Can you help me on this?  Are there any easy ways to append the protocol automatically to a URL?

I will send that URL from my server side.

Comment: server side;in which language?

Comment: The HTML won't do it for you, you'll need to add the protocol in your server-side code.  Can you tell us what server-side language you're using and show the code you use to generate the URL and add it to the page?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a possible workaround for that (I haven't tested, it's just a thought)

If you use `jQuery` in your client side code (you can do that with pure javascript also), you could do something like this to prepend the `"http://"` in all of your `iframe`'s:

```
// 'ready()' function executes when the page finishes loading
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Capture all iframes
    $('iframe').each(function(iframe) {
        // Prepend the 'http://'
        iframe.attr('src', 'http://' + $('iframe').attr('src'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

function getprotocol($URL){
if(strstr($URL,"http://")==FALSE{
$URL = str_replace("http://www","www",$URL);
}
return $URL;
}
$URL = 'www.google.com';
echo '<iframe src="'.getprotocol($URL).'">';
?>
```

**it will give you iframe of** http://www.google.com